Android suggests multiple apps for URI scheme, even with a single installed app
I am using Capacitor + React, and while implementing deep link functionality, I am observing the following issue.

On Android, when attempting to open a URI link for the app, instead of directly opening the app, I am presented with a choice of 2 applications (one is my actual app, and second I event cant open ).
Why is this happening?
Here is my AndroidManifest.xml:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
>
  <application
   android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
    android:allowBackup="false"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    
    <meta-data android:name="firebase_messaging_auto_init_enabled" android:value="false" />
    <meta-data android:name="firebase_analytics_collection_enabled" android:value="false" />

    <activity
      android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale|smallestScreenSize|screenLayout|uiMode"
      android:name="de.test.app.MainActivity"
      android:label="@string/title_activity_main"
      android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBarLaunch"
      android:launchMode="singleTask"
      android:exported="true">

      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
      </intent-filter>

      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <data android:scheme="@string/custom_url_scheme" />
      </intent-filter>

    </activity>

    <provider
      android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
      android:authorities="${applicationId}.fileprovider"
      android:exported="false"
      android:grantUriPermissions="true">
      <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
        android:resource="@xml/file_paths"></meta-data>
    </provider>
  </application>

  <!-- Permissions -->

  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
  <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.gps" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS"/>
</manifest>

It looks standard and does not contain anything unusual. Adding a host for  does not resolve the issue.
And of cousre I have only 1 app installed on my emulator, and it's not the cache issue.

"And of cousre I have only 1 app installed on my emulator" -- then what is the "dummy app", exactly?

I suspect it’s the same app, but unfortunately, it’s not working as expected. I have no idea why it’s offering 2 apps ( 1 - works well, 2 - not open at all but still presetnt in selection menu )

Are the two icons and captions the same, lining up with what you have in the <activity> element? (I cannot tell due to the redactions) Do you perhaps have both debug and release builds installed? "second I event cant open" -- if you try opening it, does Logcat show an activity start event, and if so, how does the Intent for that compare with the one that does work?

1)The icons and text are the same, I also wipe the application before launching it, so in theory there should not be 2 entities installed at the same time.
2)I see a bunch of logs, but I don't see anything special for 2 applications.
I am not an android developer, but I will try to understand the logs from longcat and maybe it will really give me some clue.

I created a starter project and it works fine, so I would say that the issue is not inside the AndroidManifest file but somewhere in the build process. It may even be related to the fact that I am using a monorepo. I don’t have a definite answer yet, but it’s definitely something related to this.
